# Parsing RSS feed - retrieve images, urls?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, ipad

Hello I am parsing a RSS And Atom feeds, and my question is how can I check for < img > and < url > tags in < description >?

There must be some sort of check. Thanks.

Here is how I parse them:

```
- (NSArray *)parseFeed:(NSURL *)feedURL{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];
    GDataXMLDocument *xmlParse = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
    GDataXMLElement *rootElement = xmlParse.rootElement;
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    if ([rootElement.name compare:@"rss"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        array = [self parseRSSFeed:rootElement];
        return array;
    } else if ([rootElement.name compare:@"feed"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        array = [self parseAtomFeed:rootElement];
        return array;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unsupported root element: %@", rootElement.name);
        return nil;
    }
}

-(NSArray *)parseRSSFeed:(GDataXMLElement *) rootElement
{
    NSMutableArray *entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {
        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
            FeedItem *itemF = [[FeedItem alloc] init];
            itemF.title = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
            itemF.description = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
            NSLog(@"IMAGE - %@", [item valueForChild:@"img"]);
            itemF.dateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
            itemF.link = [NSURL URLWithString:[item valueForChild:@"link"]];
            itemF.dateString = [item valueForChild:@"updated"];
            itemF.author = [item valueForChild:@"author"];
            [entries addObject:itemF];
            NSLog(@"RSS - %@", itemF.title);
        }
    }
    NSArray *RSSArray = [entries copy];
    return RSSArray;
}
-(NSArray *)parseAtomFeed:(GDataXMLElement *) rootElement
{
    NSMutableArray *entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *entry = [rootElement elementsForName:@"entry"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *entryElement in entry) {
        // NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        //for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
        FeedItem *itemF = [[FeedItem alloc] init];
        itemF.title = [entryElement valueForChild:@"title"];
        itemF.description = [entryElement valueForChild:@"summary"];
        NSArray *links = [entryElement elementsForName:@"link"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *link in links) {
            itemF.link = [NSURL URLWithString:[[link attributeForName:@"href"] stringValue]];
        }
        itemF.dateString = [entryElement valueForChild:@"updated"];
        NSArray *authors = [entryElement elementsForName:@"author"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *authorElement in authors) {
            itemF.author = [authorElement valueForChild:@"name"];
        }
        [entries addObject:itemF];
        NSLog(@"Atom - %@", itemF.title);
    }
    NSArray *atomArray = [entries copy];
    return atomArray;
}
```

I am parsing them using GDataXMLParser, and my own parser class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
NSString *Str=[item valueForChild:@"description"];
NSArray *tmp=[Str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<Img>"];
if([tmp count]>1){
    NSString *urlstr=[[tmp objectatindex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" </Img>" withString:@""];
}
```

Now `urlstr` contains your image url.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I thought that

```
itemF.description = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
```

is `NSString`. So you can use `componentsSeparatedByString` with "your tag". 
It will return array. In array at postion 1 you will get your img url.
This url has closing bracket "your closing tag".
Replace "your closing tag" with space. You will get image url.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: I can't do it. I get your idea, but I just cant.